# htaccess - redirect all traffic to a holding page, except for the dev domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have my dev site (dev.domain.co.uk) on the new server, ready for launch. But, the live domain has been pointed to the new server before we're ready. So, I need to show a holding page for ALL traffic to www.domain.co.uk (inc sub-pages like www.domain.co.uk/cms/login, etc), but allow dev traffic. Finally, the dev site is password protected.

Here is my .htaccess...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# All traffic to www.domain.co.uk should go to the holding page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/holding.html$1 [L]

# Dev traffic to dev.domain.co.uk...
# Rewrite to 'public' folder for Laravel
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.domain.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]

# Password protect dev.domain.co.uk
SetEnvIf Host dev.domain.co.uk passreq
AuthType Basic
AuthName "domain.co.uk"
AuthUserFile "/home/folder/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=passreq
Satisfy any
```

This is working, except for sub-pages (like www.domain.co.uk/cms/login, etc) - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to show a fixed static page for live site so don't captured URI pattern and append it after `.html`.

Keep your first rule as:

```
# All traffic to www.domain.co.uk should go to the holding page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ public/holding.html [L]
```